# Overflow-x scrolling not working with mouse wheel, only working when scrollbar is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css

My problem is with a horizontal scroll bar used on my portfolio page. I managed to make it work except one thing, it does not scroll using the mouse wheel.... if I click and drag the bar it works just fine.

You can see my project [here](http://hoverallsproblems.design-way.ro/) - click on the portfolio page and it will slide down a panel with a scroll bar. And there's my issue.

My structure is like this:

```
 <div id="portfolio"><!--this is the sliding panel-->
  <div id="width"><!--this is the thumb container-->
    <article>  
    </article>
  </div>
 </div>
```

And my CSS:

```
#portfolio {
     display:none;
     position:absolute;
     width:100%;
     height:400px; // may need to play with this 
     border-bottom:3px solid #CCC;
     top:0px;
     left:0px;
     z-index:99999;
     background-color:#fff;
     box-shadow: 0 0 37px 7px #000;
     overflow-y:hidden;
     overflow-x:scroll;
} 
#width {
    width: 3000px;
    height:320px;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    border:1px solid red;
    float: left;
}
```

Why I cannot scroll using the mouse wheel?

Answer (score 2):

In order to scroll horizontally you need to hold the shift key on your keyboard and then scroll your mouse over the horizontal canvas. It is working perfectly fine for your designed site.

Here is a jquery link for scrolling horizontally.

[Scroll Your Page Horizontally](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/horz-scroll-with-mouse-wheel/)

Comment: I am glad you like my website! :d I was not aware of the shift key thing. Thanks a lot for the jquery solution!

Comment: You're most welcome. Please follow that jquery link that I've provided. That should definetly solve your problem.

Comment: The page you link to is referring to example https://css-tricks.com/examples/HorzScrolling/ which doesn't work on Chrome 68 on a MacBook (i.e. with a mouse pad): no matter which direction you attempt to move, the page doesn't scroll at all.